# Assigning scala empty array

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I'm totally new to Scala. Here I have tried to assign a empty array to a variable, it was successful.  But when I tried to append an integer element to the variable an error occured as below:

```
var c=Array()

c: Array[Nothing] = Array()

scala> c=Array(1)

<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Nothing
       c=Array(1)
           ^
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you do `var c = Array()`, Scala computes the type as `Array[Nothing]` and therefore you can't reassign it with a `Array[Int]`. What you can do is:

```
var c : Array[Any] = Array()
c = Array(1)
```

or

```
var c : Array[Int] = Array()
c =  Array(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean we can't insert (or assign) anything to an `Array` of type `Nothing` once it's created?

Answer (score 0):

`Nothing` is the bottom type of Scala type hierarchy. It is a subtype of EVERY other type. See the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html).

If you are not deciding which type of value you want to add to the empty Array, then you declare:

```scala
var c : Array[Any] = Array()
c = Array(1)
```

If you are deciding the data type, then you declare as:

```scala
var c : Array[Int] = Array()
c =  Array(1)
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer from 8 years ago?

Comment: Stack overflow just proposed me to validate and correct a first-time answer. So I guess that's why it appeared just now. It didn't show me that there was another answer already.